# how to Unmarshal json in golang

Tags: json, go

I have a json:

```
{"code":200,
 "msg":"success",
 "data":{"url":"https:\/\/mp.weixin.qq.com\/cgi-bin\/showqrcode?ticket=gQHQ7jwAAAAAAAAAAS5odHRwOi8vd2VpeGluLnFxLmNvbS9xLzAyX3pqS0pMZlA4a1AxbEJkemhvMVoAAgQ5TGNYAwQsAQAA"}}
```

and i define a struct :

```
type Result struct {
    code int
    msg  string                 `json:"msg"`
    data map[string]interface{} `json:"data"`
}
```

for this code:

```
var res Result
json.Unmarshal(body, &res)
fmt.Println(res)
```

the output is: `{0  map[]}`

i want to get `url` in `data`, how to get it?

Answer (score 5):

You should export fields (`code`, `msg`, `data`) for `Result` by capitalizing the first letter of fields (`Code`, `Msg`, `Data`) to access (set/get) them:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Result struct {
    Code int                    `json:"code"`
    Msg  string                 `json:"msg"`
    Data map[string]interface{} `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    str := `{"code":200,"msg":"success","data":{"url":"https:\/\/mp.weixin.qq.com\/cgi-bin\/showqrcode?ticket=gQHQ7jwAAAAAAAAAAS5odHRwOi8vd2VpeGluLnFxLmNvbS9xLzAyX3pqS0pMZlA4a1AxbEJkemhvMVoAAgQ5TGNYAwQsAQAA"}}`
    var res Result
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &res)
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Play the code on https://play.golang.org/p/23ah8e_hCa

Related question: [Golang - Capitals in struct fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837432/golang-capitals-in-struct-fields)